# Auto add text in cells if Underline

Tags: excel, vba

I want to auto add text in Cells if the text in cells are underline.

example here s the text that underline

```
Happy
Sad
Good
Best
```

to

```
xHappy
xSad
xGood
xBest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following sub:

```
Sub AddTextUnderline()
    For Each cel In Range("A1:A4")
        If cel.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle Then
            cel.Value = "x" & cel.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```